# How to traverse a list until it reaches the last element, then traverse it backwards until it reaches the 1st element, then repeat?

Tags: python, list

How to traverse a list until it reaches the last element, then traverse it backwards until it reaches the 1st element, then repeat?

In other wards, how can iterate through a list specifically in a pattern that bounces off the 1st and last element?

```
e.g For a list of length=3
time=1, index=0
time=2, index=1
time=3, index=2
time=4, index=1
time=5, index=0
time=6, index=1
time=7, index=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually start with a list you can use slice and reversed to bounce it once like this:

```
def bounce(a_list):
    yield from a_list
    yield from reversed(a_list[1:-1])

for x in bounce([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print(x)
```

Repeat the bouncyness for added fun.

```
for x in itertools.cycle(bounce([0, 1, 2])):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Love this elegant solution but I need to read up more because I am unsure of what is exactly happening when you call `yield from`

Comment: In this case, `yield from` is just a short hand for `for a in a_list: yield a`. (But it is more powerful than that)

Answer (score 2):

One way using `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = [0, 1, 2]
res1 = cycle(lst + lst[-2:0:-1])


In [143]: [next(q.res1) for _ in range(10)]
Out[143]: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Thanks to @Chris_Rands for pointing out that the list comprehension can be replaced nicely with `list(itertools.islice(res1, 10))`.

Comment: `list(itertools.islice(res1, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the index can also be calculated using

```
index = (time-1)%(2*length-2)
```